# AOP Pointcut after jsp rendering

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, aop

I have a strange question.

I need to execute code really at the end of server interaction. So, if i use jsp, i need to execute it AFTER the rendering of the page.

There is a way to execute it?

i tried after this pointcut

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bin d.annotation.RequestMapping)")
```

but it leave me just after the "return ModelAndView". I need to get the very end of the server session.

I want to do it because **i need to close the Hibernate session**, avoiding the lazy initialization exception due to the closing of the session AFTER the jsp has rendered the view, and i want to avoid a script let like

```
<% HibernateManager.getSession().close() %>
```

effectively coupling the view with the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a spring-mvc interceptor - implement `HandlerIntercepetor`'s `afterCompletion(..)` method. You can also do that in a filter.

But you don't have two, for two reasons:

- you should not pass uninitialized collections to your view. Initialize everything you need in the service layer, then you won't have LazyInitializationException. In fact, [avoid lazy collections](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=645)
- even if you decide to have lazy collections, and not to initialize them in the service, spring gives you `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` (and `Filter`), and also `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` (and `Filter`) that do exactly what you need.

Comment: thank you. However, i do not prefer to remove the "laziness", because in my opinion there are more advantages with lazy instead eagering the relations. (of course we need to write code more carefully!)